# Dynamic form select with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, codeigniter-4

I have two categories in my database table.

Women Fashion and Men fashion

Under Men Fashion, I have Men Shoes

Under Women fashion, I have Female bag

I want to a javascript I will use in HTML Form select so that when one selects Women Fashion, he/she will see list of items under women fashion like women bag in the second form or when one select Man Fashion, he/she will see list of items under Men fashion like Men shoe in the second form as well.

**sample**

```
<form class="form">
  <div class="form-group">
    <select id="box1" name="num">
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
    </select>

    <select id="box2" name="letters">
      <option value="a">A</option>
      <option value="b">B</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</form>
```

**then I have this**

```
$("#box1").on('change', function () {
  var value = $(this).val();

  if (value === "1" || value === "2") {
      $("#box2").show();
  } else {
      $("#box2").hide();
  }
});
```

but don't know how to implement it using the database value

Please help

Comment: check I just updated it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**APPLY DRY PHILOSOPHY FOR THIS CODE**

It's just a test but is it that behavior you're looking for?

**HTML CODE**

```
    <form class="form">
  <div class="form-group">
    <select id="collections" name="collection">
      <option>Select a value</option>
      <option value="man">Man</option>
      <option value="woman">Woman</option>
    </select>

    <select id="box2" name="collections-items">
    </select>
  </div>
</form>
```

**JS CODE**

```
let chooseCollections = document.querySelector('#collections')
let selectItems = document.querySelector('#box2')

let manCollection = {
  categories: ["Shoes", "Shirt"]
}

let womanCollection = {
  categories: ["Dress", "Shirt"]
}

chooseCollections.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
  selectItems.querySelectorAll('*').forEach(el => el.remove());
  selectItems.style.display = "none"

  if(e.target.value === "man") {
    selectItems.style.display = "block"
    for(let i = 0; i < manCollection.categories.length; i++) {
      var option = document.createElement('option')
      var value = manCollection.categories[i]
      option.value = value
      option.innerHTML = value
      selectItems.appendChild(option)
    }
  }

  if(e.target.value === "woman") {
    selectItems.style.display = "block"
    for(let i = 0; i < womanCollection.categories.length; i++) {
      var option = document.createElement('option')
      var value = womanCollection.categories[i]
      option.value = value
      option.innerHTML = value
      selectItems.appendChild(option)
    }
  }
})
```

**CSS**

```
#box2 {
  display: none;
}
```

I've represent manCollection and womanCollection like the data you have in your database. This code is not optimized and can be more efficient but you can start with that.

https://jsfiddle.net/0aek49fr/1/